# Pervasive SQL: Can a client send multiple SQL Statements in one Database Request?

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

From a client-application, is it possible to send multiple SQL statements at once to PSQ v13?

I have a situation where I'd like to send both a delete statement and an insert statement in one call via ODBC. It would also be ideal if I could do this as a transaction so that both statements either succeed or fail.

Are either of these things possible without creating a server-side stored procedure and if so what is the proper syntax for combining multiple statements?

Comment: I have an atomic situation where this would be perfectly fine. I'm not interested in general recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to execute both statements and guarantee that both succeed without using a transaction. Transactions are only available within Stored Procedures.

What you're describing (executing a `DELETE` and `INSERT` statement in an atomic manner) is perfectly suited for a Stored Procedure using a transaction.

Something like this is a good start:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TransactionTest (:ID integer)
RETURNS (
ID INTEGER);
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM Table where ID = :ID;
    SELECT MAX(ID) from table;
  COMMIT WORK;
END;
```